# Am I using wrong version of SalesForceAPI?

Tags: soap-api, webservices, soap, .net

One of our data Provider who happens to be on SuccessFactor/SalesForce world, gave us  SOAP URl to call to work with salesForce.

Now, I added the WSDL as a **Web Reference** and now I have a client to play with. They asked me to keep the session alive by adding the SessionId in the Request in all the sub-sequent requests.

I came across the following documentation:https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

But it sounds like I am not looking at the same object for some part because  instead of Login(username, password) my object support Login(SFCredentials[])

also, I do not have access to **SessionHeaderValue** Not sure why is it different.

Is it a different version than the one mentioned in this documentation? If so, How can I access SessionHeaderValue in the new one?

Comment: This question seems very similar to the previous question you asked. Better to update the previous question with the additional information rather than start a new question.

Comment: What's the URL / WSDL they gave you, going to be hard to tell you anything useful without that.